# Unterschied zwischen schriftlichen Abschiedsformeln

Tags: phrase

Wie formal ist „Mit freundlichen Grüßen“ in Vergleich zu einem einfachen „Gruß“? Gibt es andere Abschiedsformeln, die mehr oder weniger formal sind als diese beiden?

---

[Translation] How formal is “Mit freundlichen Grüßen” in comparison to a simple “Gruß”? Are there any other set phrases, which would be more or less formal than both of these?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Mit freundlichen Grüßen* ist mehr oder weniger der Standard, wenn man nichts Besseres findet. Auch für geschäftliche Anlässe ist es meistens völlig ausreichend.

*Gruß* ist eher im freundschaftlich/kollegialen Bereich angesiedelt. In unserer Firma z. B. unterschreiben wir E-Mails zwischen Kollegen grundsätzlich mit Gruß, E-Mails an Kunden jedoch immer mit *Mit freundlichen Grüßen*.

Es gibt noch andere Formen des Abschieds:

- Hochachtungsvoll – sehr höflich und extrem formell, am besten geeignet für persönliche Briefe an hochgestellte Würdenträger, wie Bürgermeister oder Politiker
- Mit besten Empfehlungen – etwas altmodisch und kaum noch gebräuchlich
- In Erwartung Ihrer Antwort – für Bewerbungen oder formale Korrespondenzen gut zu gebrauchen, aber auch selten
- Liebe Grüße – mehr für den familiären Gebrauch, aber auch für sehr enge Freundschaften

Es gibt auch von den genannten viele Varianten, z. B. *Freundliche Grüße* anstatt *Mit freundlichen Grüßen*

Answer (score 7):

"Mit freundlichen Grüßen" is always the end of a letter starting with "Sehr geehrte(r)..."
Always use this when writing a formal letter or email.

"Gruß" is very much the bottom line of politeness. Personally, I wouldn't even use it in a private letter.

Between them are:

- Viele Grüße (this is always a good choice when you're unsure. It's still reserved enough to be polite,
- Liebe Grüße (meaning you really like the person you're writing to, never use that in a business context)
- Grüße (that's fine if you're just writing something short)
- Gruß und Kuss (very girlish and old-fashioned)

Comment: that's the less formal part. For more formal see ApoY2k's answer ^^

Answer (score 4):

Informal greetings other than "Gruss" (which sounds awkward on its own to me) would be

> Liebe Grüße
>
> Alles Liebe
>
> Viele Grüße
>
> Bis bald

The formal greeting is still

> mit freundlichen Grüßen

or

> mit freundlichem Gruß

Comment: I wouldn't use "mit freundlichem Gruß" because it spontaneously made me think of "mit völkischem Gruß" (brrrr)

Comment: I have never heard of "mit freundlichem Gruß". This seems for me as if the writer was to lazy to add two more letters.

Comment: I know "mit freundlichem Gruß" and occasionally use it, as do people around me. The thinking behind it is apparently that one person would have difficulties extending multiple greetings, so the singular is closer to the fact.

Answer (score 3):

»Mit freundlichen Grüßen« is more formal. You don’t write that to a friend.

Answer (score 1):

For hatemail, a good closing formula is "Mit dem Ihnen gebührenden Respekt" (where the preceding text usually implies that the appropriate amount of respect is exactly none), the point being that the insult is not actually made, only inferred.