# Unter welchen Umständen kann man die Schlussformel "mit herzlichen Grüßen" schreiben?

Tags: style, formality, politeness, valediction

Zur Frage nach einer Gruß- und Schlussform eines [Briefes an eine Lehrerin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/wie-sollte-ich-eine-lehrerin-die-mich-siezt-in-einer-e-mail-gr%C3%BC%C3%9Fen-und-verabsc) wird in Kommentaren die Ansicht vertreten, dass die Schlussformel "Mit herzlichen Grüßen" nicht angebracht sei.

Nun lese ich aber in meinem (akademischen) Umfeld sehr oft die Anrede "Lieber Herr Professor Soundso" und "Mit herzlichen Grüßen, Ihr". Ganz so verkehrt scheinen mir diese Grußformeln also nicht, oder zumindest nicht überall, zu sein.

Nun stellt sich mir die Frage, in welchem Umfeld und unter welchen Bedingungen diese Form der Verabschiedung angebracht ist und wann sie eben nicht angebracht ist.

Comment: Related: [Unterschied zwischen schriftlichen Abschiedsformeln](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/245/unterschied-zwischen-schriftlichen-abschiedsformeln)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut *Duden – Briefe gut und richtig schreiben!* (2006) ist die Formulierung „Mit
herzlichen Grüßen“ etwas persönlicher als „Mit freundlichen Grüßen“ und kann verwendet werden, wenn man den Adressaten näher kennt.

Answer (score 1):

> Herzliche Grüße

drückt eine gewisse persönliche Wertschätzung aus

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen

wäre etwas neutraler und unpersönlicher

> Liebe Grüße

ist eine sehr persönliche Antwort, die u.U. als zu persönlich angesehen wird (z.B. bei der Ehefrau eines Kollegen)

Comment: Nun will ich aber ein wenig persönlicher sein, es aber natürlich vermeiden, dass mein Gruß als "unangebracht" empfunden wird...

Comment: dann sind "herzliche Grüße" richtig. "Liebe Grüße" sind noch persönlicher, dies wäre u.U. unangebracht.

Answer (score 1):

Ich empfinde *Mit herzlichen Grüßen* als unpassende Mischung aus Formalität und dem Versuch, persönlich zu klingen.

*Viele Grüße* klingt sehr viel angenehmer, sympathischer und weniger steif. Es ist im Kontakt mit mir bekannten Professoren an der Uni die Standard-Schlussformel –  ich würde sie aber nur benutzten, wenn ich mir selbst sicher sein kann, dass die Person mich kennt.

Comment: "Herzliche Grüße" sind keine unpassende Mischung, es drückt ein gewisses Maß an persönlicher Wertschätzung aus.

Comment: Er sagt ja er empfinde es so; ich kann ihm da übrigens nur beipflichten. Freundliche oder liebe Grüße, je nachdem, aber "herzlich"? Klingt für meine Ohren etwas ungewohnt.